# Libgdx - changing pixmap transparency in sprite

Tags: android, libgdx

I am creating an effect that when I click a shop item it darkens the screen and some messages pop. So the message and the sprite being drawn fade in and out normally. But the sprite that has a pixmap in it won't fade.

```
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(800, 1000, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.75f);
    pixmap.fillRectangle(0, 0, 800, 1000);
    texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    pixmap.dispose();
```

and this is the sprite

```
    sprite.setColor(sprite.getColor().r, sprite.getColor().g, sprite.getColor().b, notification_alpha);
    game.batch.draw(sprite, -400, -500);
```

Comment: Use sprite.draw(batch), not batch.draw(sprite).

Comment: @Tenfour04 is correct you have to use the draw implementation of the sprite itself so it can work with its own attributes. Also, it seems you are creating a pixmap just to have a filled rectangle, why don't you create a 3x3 image and stretch it up using ninepatch?